# Redis 3 compatible with app written to Redis 2.6?

Tags: redis

We are standing up a new Redis box.

In the past, we have always used 2.4 and 2.6.

Should we run with 3 for this new box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/3.0/00-RELEASENOTES), there is no breaking change in the API.

Comment: Thank you. I had read that before posting. But did not find it 100 percent clear. On re read, I see it... At the very bottom.